# how alter a column on postgresql in migration rail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I use Rails 3.12 . Also , I work with PostgreSQL.
I would change a default value of my field on my migration.

```
change_column :tables, :field, :integer, :default => nil
change_column_default :tables, :field,nil
```

I test these instructions, but none of them work.

Can you help me ?
Thank you

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commands should work. I think the second is preferable though. However, it might be that when you generate the migration as in:

```
rails g migration change_column_default :tables, :field, nil
```

It generates a migration file in your migrate directory, inside the db directory, BUT the migration file generated is empty if you check it. I don't know why this might happen though. So when you run

```
 rake db:migrate
```

nothing is actually done.

What I think you should  do:

Go into the generated migration file in your migrate directory and add:

```
change_column_default :tables, :field, nil
```

within the change method.
Then run rake db:migrate.
Run rails console and test with some data.
**NB:** Changing the default value for postgresql columns does not affect the existing rows. It affects only future inserts as stated in section 5.5.5 [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-alter.html)

Comment: OK. Thank you for the clarification.
I also find the command to change all the lines of the table (eg User.update_all)

Comment: You welcome @Djik. Do you mean  that you found `User.update_all` or you need to know a command to change all lines of the table?